# Looping through a series to build a bar plot of percentage values in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, plot

I want to create a bar chart of percentage values instead of my numeric values.
I can get the bar chart with my raw numbers with this simple code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.array([ 6.95, 84.38, 11.82,  2.47,  1.12])
ser = pd.Series(data, index = ['wine', 'beer', 'vodka', 'champagne', 'brandy'])
ser.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

However, I want to use something like this to convert them into percentage values from the total.

```
for i in s.values:
   pct = i/s.sum()*100
   print(pct.round(2))
   pct.plot(kind='bar')


6.51
79.05
11.07
2.31
1.05
```

Because these are floats instead of a `series/dataframe`,  `pct.plot(kind = 'bar')`  does not work here.
how I can convert them to a series inside this loop?

Comment: Why not just `(ser / ser.sum() * 100).round(2).plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: ah yes you're right.  it does not like the round(2) but otherwise it works :) AttributeError: 'FloatingArray' object has no attribute 'round'

Comment: Interesting. [`Series.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) should certainly work. But otherwise glad you have something that works :-)